# How to upload a image to directory

Tags: php

I used the following code to upload an image to a folder. My folder name is ADS. Please help me to upload that image to my ADS directory.

root - localhost/dc/upload.php
(the code is in this location)

The image should be added to the folder in location localhost/dc/ADS

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (is_array($_FILES)) {
        $file = $_FILES['myImage']['tmp_name']; 
        $source_properties = getimagesize($file);
        $image_type = $source_properties[2]; 

        if ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {   
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);  
            echo $target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id,$source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            echo imagejpeg($target_layer,$_FILES['myImage']['name']);
        } elseif ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {  
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            echo$target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id,$source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            echo imagegif($target_layer,$_FILES['myImage']['name'] );
        } elseif ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefrompng($file); 
            echo$target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id,$source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            echo imagepng($target_layer,$_FILES['myImage']['name']);
        }
    }
}

function fn_resize($image_resource_id,$width,$height) 
{
    $target_width =540;
    $target_height =400;
    $target_layer=imagecreatetruecolor($target_width,$target_height);
    imagecopyresampled($target_layer,$image_resource_id,0,0,0,0,$target_width,$target_height, $width,$height);
    return $target_layer;
}
```

When I use this code the image is displayed as in the Image1. I need it be like in Image2 without any change to the image and also I need to have a text or image watermark on the image as in the Image3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PHP functions imagepng imagegif and imagejpeg all have an argument to pass a file name to. I refactored your code to show this.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (is_array($_FILES)) {
        $file = $_FILES['myImage']['tmp_name'];
        $source_properties = getimagesize($file);
        $image_type = $source_properties[2];

        if ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            echo $target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id, $source_properties[0], $source_properties[1]);
            imagejpeg($target_layer, "localhost/dc/ADS/" . $_FILES['myImage']['name']);
        }
        elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            echo$target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id, $source_properties[0], $source_properties[1]);
            imagegif($target_layer, "localhost/dc/ADS/" . $_FILES['myImage']['name']);
        }
        elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            echo$target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id, $source_properties[0], $source_properties[1]);
            imagepng($target_layer, "localhost/dc/ADS/" . $_FILES['myImage']['name']);
        }
    }
}

function fn_resize($image_resource_id, $width, $height) {
    $target_width = 540;
    $target_height = 400;
    $target_layer = imagecreatetruecolor($target_width, $target_height);
    imagecopyresampled($target_layer, $image_resource_id, 0, 0, 0, 0, $target_width, $target_height, $width, $height);
    return $target_layer;
}
```

Comment: imagepng($target_layer, $_FILES['myImage']['name'], "localhost/dc/ADS/image.png");
        
When I use this code line it won't move to the folder I need. It gives the following error

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 3 to be long,

Comment: Wow, I messed up on the code lol. I edited the above code to reflect what should be the correct code.